# Using datasource-proxy is there a way to not log query parameters?

Tags: spring-boot

I am looking for a way to log all of the query information that is contained within this framework http://ttddyy.github.io/datasource-proxy/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#query-logging-listener however I want to exclude logging of the query parameters.  Is there a way to do this using datasource-proxy?  If not what alternatives do I have?  I am currently using spring boot 2.1.1.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is... when you configure your DatasourceProxy you can add an LoggingListener e.g. for SLF4J:

```
SLF4JQueryLoggingListener loggingListener = new SLF4JQueryLoggingListener();
loggingListener.setQueryLogEntryCreator(new NoParamsQueryLogEntryCreator);
this.dataSource = ProxyDataSourceBuilder.create(dataSource)
      .name("MyDS")
      .listener(loggingListener)
      .build();
```

the NoParamsQueryLogEntryCreator can look like this:

```
public class NoParamsQueryLogEntryCreator extends DefaultQueryLogEntryCreator {
   @Override
   protected SortedMap<String, String> getParametersToDisplay(List<ParameterSetOperation> params) {
     // here you can manipulate the Parameter List ... obfucating or remove params
     return super.getParametersToDisplay(params);
   }
}
```

Comment: I added this to my project 
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.gavlyukovskiy</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-proxy-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

and added property
```logging.level.net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener=debug```
but nothing is work.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'dataSource' is expected to be of type 'com.hitop.application.tenancy.DynamicTenantAwareRoutingSource' but was actually of type 'com.github.gavlyukovskiy.boot.jdbc.decorator.DecoratedDataSource'